# contract deployment fine on rinkeby but pending on mainnet

Tags: contract-deployment, pending-transactions, mainnet

I deployed smart contract on rinkeby using web3 script and it works fine, actually deployed many times.

Today I tried to deploy on main net and transaction is pending since 40 mins, gas limit is good enough and account has ether balance as well.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0f6ec341347dfd107c278c5af34b8d4de1822dd3bcc8ef5460e8865b21417543

Nonce is 0 as it is first transaction from this account.

What could be the reason of pending?

Comment: Gas price seems a bit low. See here: https://ethgasstation.info/

Comment: so if I try with 36 wei with same nonce, what will happen with pending transaction, failed?

Comment: so if I try with 36 wei with same nonce, what will happen with pending transaction, failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Newti commented your gas price is too low. Rinkeby is Proof-of-Authority which doesn't care about gas prices so it's not a perfect test network.

You mentioned that "gas limit is good". You are probably mixing up the concepts of "gas limit" and "gas price". "Gas limit" tells what is the maximum amount of gas you allow the transaction to spend. "Gas price" says how much you are willing to pay for each gas unit spent - the more you specify the faster miners include your transaction in a block.

The site https://ethgasstation.info/ gives good estimates about the gas price you should use.

If you send a new transaction with the same nonce and higher gas price the new transaction will most likely be mined first and the first transaction becomes invalid as the nonce has been used already.